# How to convert from a Pytroch Tensor from mathematically a column vector to a column matrix?

Tags: matrix, vector, transpose, pytorch, tensor

I am working with tensors in pytorch.
How can I convert a tensor corresponding to a column vector to a tensor corresponding to its transpose?

```
import numpy as np
coef = torch.from_numpy(np.arange(1.0, 5.0)).float()
print(coef)
print(coef.size())
```

Currently the size of `coef` is `[4]` but I want it to be `[4, 1]` with the same content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to achieve in PyTorch. You can use the [`view()`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view) method.

```
coef = coef.view(4, 1)
print(coef.size()) # now the shape will be [4, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

While using `.view` is certainly a good option in general I want to add, for completeness' sake, that there is also the `.unsqueeze()` method which adds an extra dimension at a specified index (contrary to the `.squeeze()` method which removes unity dimensions):

```
>>> coef = coef.unsqueeze(-1) # add extra dimension at the end
>>> coef.shape
torch.Size([4, 1])
```

For transpositions in general you can use the `.t()` method.

Comment: or for a really quick method try 
`coef = coef[:,None]`